# SQL: Error function returned without value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I get function returned without error when i run the query, i hope you can help me

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loginSesion(pPassword VARCHAR2, pUser VARCHAR2) 
RETURN NUMBER

IS
   vPassword VARCHAR2(100);
   vUsername VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

   SELECT Person.Username, Person.Password INTO vUsername, vPassword
   FROM Person
   WHERE Person.Password = pPassword and Person.Username = pUser;
   EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       vPassword := NULL;
       vUsername := NULL;
   IF vPassword IS NULL OR vUsername IS NULL THEN
       RETURN FALSE;
   ELSE
       RETURN TRUE;

   END IF;

END loginSesion;
```

I am new in sql.

Comment: And what do you want it to do? You intend to return a NUMBER but you are returning `true` or `false`...

Comment: You are only returning from the EXCEPTION block. If the exception is not thrown (the SELECT actually succeeds), then the EXCEPTION block is never entered.

Comment: Well change the false by 0 and true by 1, i want to return a number

Comment: @mathguy how is the second part of the exception? To fix the code, please can you help me

Comment: Are you really storing passwords in a table and passing them around in queries?

Comment: @tbone - I think it's a fair assumption (and I hope this is true!) that the OP is just playing/learning, he is not actually touching a password table in a production system.

Comment: @Danny - I already showed you how to fix the code in my Answer. If it is still unclear, please say so (and don't forget to show WHAT is unclear). If instead you want me to post the full code after corrections, sorry but I don't do that. I help, but I don't write people's homework for them.

Comment: @mathguy I don't know, maybe this is a school assigment or something else, but just jumped out at me as a big red flag (maybe the poster works for Equifax? sorry, couldn't resist ;-)

Comment: Oh thanks @mathguy, i figured out how to fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have explained you only return a value *if* an exception occurred. If everything is OK, you don't return something. That can be fixed using the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loginSesion(pPassword VARCHAR2, pUser VARCHAR2) 
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
   vPassword VARCHAR2(100);
   vUsername VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   SELECT Person.Username, Person.Password INTO vUsername, vPassword
   FROM Person
   WHERE Person.Password = pPassword and Person.Username = pUser;

   -- executed when a row was found
   return 1;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

   -- executed when no row was found
   RETURN 0;
END loginSesion;
/
```

---

Using an exception as a replacement for an `IF` condition is a bit of a code-smell (of course this is a bit subjective).

As you never use the values of the returned row, you can simplify the function to simply count the number of rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loginSesion(pPassword VARCHAR2, pUser VARCHAR2) 
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
   l_count integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) 
     into l_count;
   FROM Person
   WHERE Person.Password = pPassword 
     and Person.Username = pUser;

   if l_count = 0 then 
     return 0;
   else 
     return 1;
   end if;

END loginSesion;
/
```

If the calling code treats zero as "false" and anything greater then zero as  "true", then you can remove the `if` and simply use `return l_count;`

---

The `count()` would also be necessary in case `username` is **not** unique (which I would find very strange). Because if there were two users with the same username, the select in the first solution would then throw a "select returned more then one row" exception.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to return 1 to represent "true" if the combination of username and password is found, and 0 to represent "false" otherwise, then:

- ADD  `return 1` right after the SELECT and **before** the EXCEPTION block
- ADD `return 0` in the EXCEPTION block

You don't need to assign anything in the EXCEPTION block, just say `when no data found then return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Pro Tip. Oracle has something like pls_warrinings. You can turn it on. And lot of stupid mistake can be easy to find.

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS = 'ENABLE:ALL'; - turn on 
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS = 'DISABLE:ALL'; - turn off
```

After fix compilation errors from your example.(`[Error] PLS-00382 (16: 15): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type` )

Next "compilation" shows you

```
[Warning] PLW-05018 (1: 1): PLW-05018: unit LOGINSESION omitted optional AUTHID clause; default value DEFINER used
[Warning] PLW-06002 (15: 8): PLW-06002: Unreachable code
[Warning] PLW-05005 (1: 1): PLW-05005: subprogram LOGINSESION returns without value at line 18
```

First warning is not relevant.
`PLW-06002: Unreachable code` is becouse of this.

```
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       vPassword := NULL;
       vUsername := NULL;
   IF vPassword IS NULL OR vUsername IS NULL THEN
       RETURN 0;
   ELSE
       RETURN 1; -- <-- this part is Unreachable (vPassword IS NULL OR vUsername IS null is allways ture)



   END IF;
```

`PLW-05005: subprogram LOGINSESION returns without value at line 18`  because value is not returned when select has one row.

Correct version are.

```
create or replace function loginSesion(pPassword varchar2, pUser varchar2)
  return number
is
    vPassword VARCHAR2(100);
   vUsername VARCHAR2(100);
begin
 SELECT Person.Username, Person.Password INTO vUsername, vPassword FROM Person WHERE Person.Password = pPassword and Person.Username = pUser;
   return 0;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return 0; 
end loginSesion;
/

create or replace function loginSesion(pPassword varchar2, pUser varchar2)
  return number
is
   vResutl number;
begin
 SELECT count(*) into vResutl  FROM Person WHERE Person.Password = pPassword and Person.Username = pUser;
  return vResutl;
end loginSesion;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning character instead of Number. So your need to change return type values.

**code :**

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loginSesion(pPassword VARCHAR2, pUser VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER

    IS
       vPassword VARCHAR2(100);
       vUsername VARCHAR2(100);

    BEGIN
      BEGIN
       SELECT Person.Username, Person.Password INTO vUsername, vPassword
       FROM Person
       WHERE Person.Password = pPassword and Person.Username = pUser;
       EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
           vPassword := NULL;
           vUsername := NULL;
            RETURN 0;
       END;
       IF vPassword IS NULL OR vUsername IS NULL THEN
           RETURN 0;
       ELSE
           RETURN 1;

       END IF;
    exception 
          when others then 
          RETURN 0;
          --dbms_output.put_line('Return' || ' - ' || sqlerrm);
    END loginSesion;
```

Comment: You're missing the return clause if the exception isn't thrown.